# Pixy CMUCAM5 Open Source Example Code Modulo Operation

Tags: c, arduino, modulo

I've been busy with the PIXYCAM and Arduino Uno and I have downloaded the code below from their site. now there's an (i%50) operation and I don't know what it does? can someone please explain this part of the code for me please?

```
    #include <SPI.h>
    #include <Pixy.h>
    Pixy pixy;
    void setup()
    {
       Serial.begin(9600);
       Serial.print(“Starting...\n”);
       pixy.init();
    }
    void loop()
    {
       static int i = 0;
       int j;
       uint16_t blocks;
       char buf[32];
       blocks = pixy.getBlocks();
       if (blocks)
       {
          i++;
          if (i%50==0)
          {
             sprintf(buf, “Detected %d:\n”, blocks);
             Serial.print(buf);
             for (j=0; j<blocks; j++)
             {
                sprintf(buf, “ block %d: “, j);
                Serial.print(buf);
                pixy.blocks[j].print();
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It performs the contents of the if-clause when i is an integer multiple of 50, so the expression is true when i = 50, 100, 150, ...

I don't know anything about the PIXYCAM, but the code seems to print a set of blocks every once in a while...

Comment: To inform you about the PIXYCAM, It's a 50Hz camera module, so that's probably why there's a I%50 as a modulo. I want to do something every 50 Frames.

Comment: The 50Hz would make sense.  Glad to be of assistance

Answer (score 0):

```
 i++;
 if (i%50==0)
```

Do this (print) every 50 frames because printing every frame would bog down the Arduino.

The % sign is the remainder of i/50, in other words, i mod 50. This means that the codes only executes every 50th frame.